# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:for a simple linear regression model in Python- Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

I am trying to learn Python and Data Science out of scratch using on line material.

I have just tried to create a simple linear regression model to get some hands on practice after reading a lot of material. However, I get the following error while trying to do it.

Can you kindly help to understand this error and see what I have done wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numpy.random import randn
np.random.seed(101)

df3=pd.DataFrame(randn(5,2),index ='0 1 2 3 4'.split(), columns='Test Price'.split())

y= df3['Price']
x= df3['Test']

import sklearn.model_selection as model_selection
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=101)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm2= LinearRegression()

lm2.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Error

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-2.01816824  0.65111795  0.90796945 -0.84807698].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 1):

check the doc [Link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

> Parameters
>
> X: {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features) Training
>   data

So you will have to reshape your X to `(n_samples, 1)` in your case.

Use

`lm2.fit(X_train.values.reshape(-1,1),y_train)`

Comment: Why did I get that error? I am trying to understand.

Comment: As the docs says the 'X' should be of size `(n_samples, n_features)`. However you have only one feature  per sample so the shape is `(n_samples)` which you have to reshape it to `(n_samples, 1)` which is done using `reshape(-1,1)`. since it is a series you to first convert it to numpy array before reshape using `values` method.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still new to this forum so when I wanted to mark your answer as helpful it required me to have reputation score of 15. Otherwise your answer helped me. Thank you again.